# Rails pass objects to Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view, partial-views, dry

I have a lot of forms that start with:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger", id="error">
    <p>Please correct the following error(s):</p>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Only I have it for @user, @item, etc etc. , so I thought to DRY it up like this:

```
<%= render "layouts/errors", locals: { obj: @status } %>

<!-- layouts/errors file -->
<% if obj.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger", id="error">
    <p>Please correct the following error(s):</p>
    <ul>
    <% obj.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But this causes the error: `ActionView::Template::Error: undefined local variable or method`obj' for #<#:0x007fce0c36a858>`

How do I successfully pass this object through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `partial:` key when calling `render`:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/errors", locals: { obj: @status } %>
```